# Return Attachments from Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, images, attachments

I'm a fairly new WP developer. I am trying to get my `portfolio.php` to display all images attached to my custom post type 'portfolio', and then display them in a masonry format. I've managed to get them to show without the `$post->post_type` query, but not much success when trying to limit WP to retrieving images attached to my custom post type. Any help will be much appreciated, and thanks in advance!

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="portfolio-wrapper">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'portfolio'  ) {
    $attachments = get_posts( array (
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    ) );

     if ( $attachments ) {
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_url ($attachment->ID);
            echo '<div class="portfolio-item">';
            echo '<a href="'.$imgurl.'" rel="lightbox[portfolio-home]"><img class="portfolio" src="'.$imgurl.'"></a>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }
}
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As requested, my solution. Not very elegant, but it works:

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        while($query->have_posts()){
            $query->the_post();
            $image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status'         => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
    while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
        $image_query->the_post();
        $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_the_ID() );
        echo '<div class="portfolio-item">';
        echo '<a href="'.$imgurl.'" rel="lightbox[portfolio-home]"><img class="portfolio" src="'.$imgurl.'"></a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Found an appropriate script. Had to use WP_Query. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider adding your solution as an answer, so that others can learn from it and question doesn't haunt site as unanswered. :)

Comment: Add your "As requested, my solution. Not very elegant, but it works:" part as an answer in the answer block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution (edited incorrectly into the question) should be workable but you should be able to accomplish the same with fewer queries.

1. Pull your portfolio `ID`s-- note the `fields` argument.
2. Then pull your attachments with those `ID`s as the parent post.
3. Then you only loop over the one image array.

That works out to two primary queries. To wit:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
  ) 
);
$image_query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_status' => 'inherit', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_parent__in' => $query->posts, 
    'order' => 'DESC' 
  ) 
);

if( $image_query->have_posts() ){
  while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
      $image_query->the_post();
      $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_the_ID() );
      echo '<div class="portfolio-item">';
      echo '<a href="'.$imgurl.'" rel="lightbox[portfolio-home]"><img class="portfolio" src="'.$imgurl.'"></a>';
      echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

The way you are doing it  would mean one query for the `portfolio` posts, plus another image query for each `portfolio` result. That could mean dozens, hundreds, or even more queries depending on the size of your database.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is far more elegant than mine. I will be using this instead.